# Nginx virtual hosts not working

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, virtual-hosts

I recorded a video https://youtu.be/dmezVzASr5A

I have:

- linux ubuntu 16.04 (Lubuntu)
- nginx 1.10
- php7.0-fpm
- php7.0
- mysql 5.7

I did:

- created domain /etc/hosts (test2.test)
- created virtual hosts withing sites-available folder (test2.test file)
- restarted, reloaded nginx server (sudo service nginx stop...restart...reload)
- created symlink `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test2.test /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

symlink proof:

```
dima@dima-Lenovo-G50-30:~/www/nginx/test2.ru$ ls -ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
total 0
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 май 21 16:33 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 май 21 16:44 test2.test -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/test2.test
```

Problem is when i try to open in browser http://test2.test, i get:

```
404 Not Found

nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

This files are not opening:

- index.html
- test.html
- index.php

within `/var/www/html` i have `info.php` with content `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`. `http://localhost/info.php` successfully displays php info.

My permissions:

```
dima@dima-Lenovo-G50-30:~/www/nginx/test2.ru$ ls -la
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 май 21 16:59 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 dima     dima     4096 май 21 13:14 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data  111 фев 21 13:34 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   26 май 21 13:15 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data    5 май 21 16:59 test.html
dima@dima-Lenovo-G50-30:~/www/nginx/test2.ru$
```

My virtual hosts:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name test2.test;

    root /home/dima/www/nginx/test2.ru;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #autoindex on;
    }
}
```

nginx logs:

error.log.1:
many errors like:

```
2016/05/26 08:46:28 [crit] 1066#1066: *1 stat() "/home/dima/www/nginx/test2.ru/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: test2.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "test2.test"
```

ls -la:

```
dima@dima-Lenovo-G50-30:~/www/nginx$ ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  4 dima     dima     4096 май 21 13:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 10 dima     dima     4096 май 21 12:52 ..
drwxrwxr-x  5 dima     dima     4096 май 21 12:52 test1.ru
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 май 21 16:59 test2.ru
dima@dima-Lenovo-G50-30:~/www/nginx$
```

within test2.ru folder:

```
dima@dima-Lenovo-G50-30:~/www/nginx/test2.ru$ ls -la
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 май 21 16:59 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 dima     dima     4096 май 21 13:14 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data  111 фев 21 13:34 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   26 май 21 13:15 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data    5 май 21 16:59 test.html
dima@dima-Lenovo-G50-30:~/www/nginx/test2.ru$
```

**UPD** I have fixed. It was permissions problem. I changed some permisisions and it worked, but i don't know and remvemebr exactly what i did, but it works

Comment: Have you enabled the site ? I mean symlinked to sites-enabled ?

Comment: yes, i added with ln -s command

Comment: Can you share the Nginx log after a restart? Tail the last 50 lines and share it as a pastebin/gist or something.

Comment: i don't know how to do that. where i can find log file?

Comment: Logs are located here, unless you change the path /var/log/nginx

Comment: i published a logs info, see main post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to give execute access to the files in that /home/dima/www/nginx/test2.ru folder.  Nginx needs to execute the php files, not only read the files.